# Fail to deploy my spring boot application to asw beanwalk

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I developed a spring boot project on Intellij, which is only backend for now. and wanna deploy it to aws.
I followed below 
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/08/07/deploy-a-spring-boot-app-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk

Like he said ,I also get 502 error at first, then I did add server_port 5000 according to him
but I still get 502 bad gateway

http://personalprojectmanagement-env.eba-xzze9hnr.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/  is my website

anyone can help?

Thanks

Comment: And you defined `SERVER_PORT` and not `server_port`?

Comment: @Thomas__ Hi, I defined SERVER_PORT,   Upper case

Comment: After applying the configuration did it redeploy? What do the logs say? Might be best defining the port as 5000 in your application.properties/yaml; I've never had issues that way